# How to transfer the entire array with card data to a function? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, native

```
const initialCards = [
  {
      name: 'a',
      link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/arkhyz.jpg'
  },
  {
      name: 'Челябинская область',
      link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/chelyabinsk-oblast.jpg'
  },
  {
      name: 'b',
      link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/ivanovo.jpg'
  },
  {
      name: 'c',
      link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/kamchatka.jpg'
  },
  {
      name: 'd',
      link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/kholmogorsky-rayon.jpg'
  },
  {
      name: 'e',
      link: 'https://pictures.s3.yandex.net/frontend-developer/cards-compressed/baikal.jpg'
  }
];
```

here is the function, at the moment individual parameters are passed.

```
function createCard(name, link) {
  const cardTemplate = document.querySelector('#card-template').content;
  const cardElement = cardTemplate.cloneNode(true);
  cardElement.querySelector('.place__name').textContent = name;
  cardElement.querySelector('.place__image').src = link;

  cardElement.querySelector('.place__like').addEventListener('click', handleClickLike);
  cardElement.querySelector('.place__image').addEventListener('click', handleDigitClick);


  return cardElement;
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you could use destructuring: `function createCard({name, link})` and call the function with a single card object, e.g.`createCard(initialCards[0])`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the array and for each item call the function

```js
const createdCards = initialCards.map(card => createCard(card.name, cart.link));
```